# SQL - Handling IS NULL in a script

Tags: sql, t-sql, null

I've made a SQL script with a bunch of if/else blocks doing stuff based on the data received. After testing I've noticed that I had forgotten about "= NULL" not working in SQL.
Is there a decent way of handling possible null values in a SQL script?

My script used to contain things like:

```
SET @PreviousFolderId = (
    SELECT TOP(1) ObjectId
    FROM Document.DocumentFolder 
    WHERE Name = @FolderName
    AND ParentFolderId = @ParentFolderId
    ORDER BY CreationDate
)
```

Clearly this won't work if @ParentFolderId is NULL.
The workaround I came up with is the following (please don't laugh):

```
DECLARE @PreviousFolderIdTable TABLE (PreviousFolderId INT)
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Query = 
'SELECT TOP(1) ObjectId
    FROM Document.DocumentFolder 
    WHERE Name = ''' + @FolderName + '''
    AND ParentFolderId '
IF @ParentFolderId IS NULL
SET @Query += 'IS NULL'
ELSE SET @Query += CONCAT('= ',@ParentFolderId)
SET @Query += '
ORDER BY CreationDate'
DELETE FROM @PreviousFolderIdTable
INSERT INTO @PreviousFolderIdTable
EXECUTE(@Query)
SET @PreviousFolderId = (
    SELECT TOP(1) PreviousFolderId
    FROM @PreviousFolderIdTable
    ORDER BY PreviousFolderId
)
```

There has to be a better way to achieve the same effect. Not only is there way too much code to achieve this, it would take a while for someone to comprehend what I'm trying to do here, compared to the first query being easily readable.

Comment: What do you want when @FolderId is null - rows where Name too is null, or all rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow an empty `@ParentFolderId` you can use `OR` within your `WHERE`:

```
WHERE Name = @FolderName
  AND (@ParentFolderId IS NULL OR ParentFolderId = @ParentFolderId)
```

If you want to deal with `NULL` as a normal value you can use this

```
WHERE Name = @FolderName
  AND (ParentFolder IS NULL AND @ParentFolderId IS NULL OR ParentFolderId = @ParentFolderId)
```

Comment: This seems like it wouldn't entirely have the same effect. Wouldn't this only match by name if @ParentFolderId is NULL? Meaning it would also match records where ParentFolderId isn't NULL? My guess is it should be: 
`    AND ((@ParentFolderId IS NULL AND ParentFolderId IS NULL )OR ParentFolderId = @ParentFolderId)`
Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @DriesGeenen `AND` is tighter than `OR` (see [*operator precedence*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017))... Just try it out and play with combinations. you can add sample data and the expected output for various input. Best was a [mcve].